# Google Calendar & Outlook Calendar 2-Way Sync as of February, 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar, google-sync

I just got a new laptop and can't sync my outlook calendar with my google calendar. How can this be done now that google has stopped 2-way sync?

Answer (score 1):

You can try third-party tool - Sync2 and choose two-way synchronization of your Google and Outlook calendars between two or more devices. 
Free download:
http://www.sync2.com/